# Installing mongodb server on Ubuntu 20.10 and got unmet dependencies error

Tags: mongodb, 20.10

I was installing `mongodb` server on Ubuntu 20.10 and got unmet dependencies error as shown in the below images:

[image: unmet dependencies 1]

[image: unmet dependencies 2]

Comment: Hmmm. All of those packages have candidates in 20.10 (-main) that meet the requirements for both version and architecture. Can you please show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`?

Comment: I had added it on the upper link

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb don't work when you install the package in the system.

The best way at this time is to use the docker of mongo.
https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/